# Google Maps Link Formatting to Search Nearby + Place Marker at the centre

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to format a link to open Google Maps so that it shows nearby amenities (i.e. Restaurants) for a given lat/lng, but also shows a marker at the lat/lng centre point.

I can do each separately, but I'm having trouble combining them into one URL.

Search nearby restaurants:
https://www.google.ca/maps/search/restaurant/@44.9155262,-78.0602643,12z

Show a marker:
https://www.google.ca/maps?q=44.9155262,-78.0602643

Any help would be appreciated